# Truncating the Text without giving setMaxLength();

Tags: android, text, truncate, dynamically-generated

I have a huge string which I have to truncate at one point, As I have to run the code in different devices with different screen sizes, problem arises with no. of lines per view in different devices. for this, obviously I should not use any methods like setMaxLength() but whereever in the the Internet I see the method every one is prescribing to set no. of lines, which is not suitable for my case.

Please some one prescribe me a procedure to truncate the text dynamically but not according to the number of lines.

Comment: make it scroallble :)

Comment: This I had to mention before in the question should not scroll ........ Thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

If you want to truncate and not wrap the text, you could consider using 
[setEllipsize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setEllipsize%28android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt%29).

Comment: yes you can setEllipsize at end or starting or middle , that is not a problem but I should truncate at the particular point of the view not according to the text length

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't understand something. What exactly do you want? A shorter text on the same TextView?

Comment: ellipsize is something to get the three dots at the end but if to truncate the text dynamically at the end of the layout. here my textView is spread throughout the layout

Comment: Have you considered using a specific TextView length per screen size? That way your TextView won't be spread through the layout.

Comment: Yes I have kept the textView in layout with match Parent but this is not the issue the issue is with truncating  the text dyanamically without giving the max line for the textview